# Splash Screen 2.79 test render does not work

Tags: rendering

I downloaded the Blender 2.79 splash screen demo file:
https://cloud.blender.org/p/gallery/59819ee681191741ad07d283
I change nothing and hit directly the render button. But all I get is a blurry image without the agent.
Any suggestions what I'm doing wrong?

Greetings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select frame 11 for rendering. Otherwise the initial frame is rendered which is a blurry screen with a small pose of the agent in the background.